# PC turns on for no reason

Tags: windows-7, usb, sleep

My PC turns on automatically from S3 suspend for no reason.

**Disabled:**

- Wake on LAN
- Wake on Mouse

**Triggers that turn the PC on from S3 suspend:**

1. No apparent cause
2. When the power plug on the same power bar (UPS) is detached or attached (even if the device is something like a phone charger that is not electrically connected to the PC)
3. When a USB device connected to the PC (thru Hub or directly) is detached or attached

**PowerCfg -lastwake reports:**
Wake Source [0]
  Type: Device
  Friendly Name:
  Description: USB Root Hub
  Manufacturer: (Standard USB Host Controller)

**Question:**
Why is this happening?

Comment: You probably answered your own question when you said that your PC wakes up when you connect or disconnect a USB device to/from your PC.

Comment: But why does this happen, how to stop its recurrence?  ie: configuration error or faulty motherboard

Comment: Probably a BIOS setting. It'd be best to look in the BIOS' power settings for anything related to USB (and wake on magic packet settings if you don't need that either).